# Ruby on Rails - In "select_date" the number of days in dropdown should come according to month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

select_date contains the Days dropdown as 31 days. Any way to load number of days based on month selection..

eg: If we select

```
             May 2014 - it should show 1..31 in Days dropdown

             june 2013 - it should show 1..30 in Days dropdown
```

Comment: Instead of doing this through ruby, why are you not doing this with a javascript Datepicker?

Comment: need to use only keyboard..

Comment: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/183310

Comment: yes..I am validating after form submission..I posted here to know any other way instead of validation or rescuing...